# Understanding html code

Tags: html, textfield

I am having a problem trying to understand a line of code. The code is below:

```
<input name="startDay" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?=$startDay?>">
```

This code line was part of the code for creating a table and so far, I believe that it basically creates a text field that allows the user to input data and allow us to retrieve the input using the name startday with php code.

The variable $startDay is the variable that will receive the input of the value inputted by the user. However, I do not understand this part of the code and the way it is formatted:

```
value="<?=$startDay?>"
```

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: It's a PHP short tag. http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `value="<?=$startDay?>"` this code will set the default value for the input which you have set.

and `<?= ?>` this syntax is short method for directly echoing variable,

`<?=$startDay?>` is equal to `<?php echo $startDay; ?>`

Comment: Can I be able to write <?php echo $startDay = 5; ?> which assigns a value to $startDay and prints it out on the text field?

Comment: @user2548635 yes, but you do not need to add `$startDay` because you only need to add `5` so i prefer you should write `<?php echo 5; ?>`

Comment: I understand what you're saying. It's just that I plan to set the value of $startDay to the current day so I can't set a concrete value for it.

Answer (score 0):

It simply tells that you assigning `$startDay` variable value into input text. It does not assign value of your input back to `$startDay` variable, just prints `$startDay`  value in input element.

Answer (score 0):

ok the line you have is written in ***php***. this outputs a text field where **$startDay** is written out in php by the server as a default value for that input field. so in other words, the server is filling out that form in php using a variable it already has.

the `<?` and `?>` are opening and closing php tags. **$startDay** is the php variable